# Line break text in \text{} in math mode without splitting math formula

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

I wrote the following equation with text inside:

```
\begin{equation*}
\text{$\Gamma$ schedulabile con RM in presenza di preemption} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{C_i}{T_i} \leq n \, \left( 2^{1/n} - 1 \right)
\end{equation*}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to break only the text line without affecting the math formula. E.g. the line break should occur after RM, and should affect only what I wrote inside \text{}.

Comment: replace `\text` by `\parbox{3cm}`

Comment: Perfect @DavidCarlisle it's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `\text` by `\parbox{3cm}` or perhaps `\parbox[t]{3cm}` or whatever width you need to have a box that allows line breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions: one with `pbox` package, and its eponymous command, which is like `\parbox{some length}`, except the length is the *maximum* length of the box, and another solution with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\pbox{40mm}{$\Gamma$ schedulabile con RM\\ in presenza di preemption} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{C_i}{T_i} \leq n \, \left( 2^{1/n} - 1 \right)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\Centerstack[l]{$\Gamma$ schedulabile con RM\\ in presenza di preemption} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{C_i}{T_i} \leq n \, \left( 2^{1/n} - 1 \right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Bernard

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `tabular`. This allows to make no guess on the desired width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  $\Gamma$ schedulabile con RM \\
  in presenza di preemption
\end{tabular}
\iff
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{C_i}{T_i} \leq n ( 2^{1/n} - 1 )
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed `\,`, `\left` and `\right`. They serve no purpose and actually make the formula ambiguous

[image]

In the second case the parentheses are way too big and they seem to mark a side condition, rather than a factor.